# Display model JSON data in template using Ember.js

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

This is kind of hard to phrase in a question, but hopefully my JSON will help explain.

```
var lodges = [
    {
        id: 1,
        lodgesName: 'Matt\'s Awesome Lodge',
        lodgeOwnersName: 'Matthew D',
        lodgeStreetAddress: '5555 J lane',
        lodgeCity: 'Salt Lake city',
        lodgeZip: '11111',
        lodgeState: 'Utah',
        favorites: [
            {
                id: 1,
                lodge_id: 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        lodgesName: 'Some Historic Lodge',
        lodgeOwnersName: 'Santa Claus',
        lodgeStreetAddress: '1 Clearwater Road',
        lodgeCity: 'Grand Marais',
        lodgeZip: '55555',
        lodgeState: 'Minnesota',
        favorites: [
            {
                id: 1,
                lodge_id: 1
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

This is my model, containing two lodges. I want to access the favorites within each lodge, using the `lodge_id` in the `favorites` array, to grab the `lodgesName` with the associated lodge id. Example: each lodge owner has a list of lodges he/she "favorites". I want to view a list of the titles that they have favorited. In this provided example, they have favorited each other.

My route is:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('lodges');  
  this.resource('lodge', {path: '/lodge/:lodge_id'}, function() {
    this.resource('favorites', function() {
        this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

I have tried to wrap my head around how everything interacts using Ember, but have been unable to figure this out. What do I need to set up in a controller to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Routes `model` hook to setup the data wired to the controller (assuming lodges are available in `App.lodges`):

```
App.LodgeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var lodges = App.lodges;
    return lodges.findProperty('id', params.lodge_id);
  }
});

App.FavoritesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var lodges = App.lodges;
    var lodge = this.modelFor('lodge');
    return lodge.favorites.map(function(favorite) {
      return lodges.findProperty('id', favorite.lodge_id);
    });
  }
});
```

And then in your favorites template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="favorites">
  <ul>
    {{#each content}}
      <li>{{lodgesName}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```